# Cancelled job still running after cancelAndJoin()

Tags: android, kotlin, jobs, cancellation, transient

I have an Android screen update job that gets called whenever the slider is moved.
Before calling it again I call cancelAndJoin(). Still, sometimes there is more than one instance of the update running at the same time, causing problems.

So my code looks like this:

```
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch{

updateJob.cancelAndJoin()

updateJob=launch {long update....}

}
```

Any help on how to absolutely make sure that there is no single instance of update running before calling it again?

Comment: Could you share the code of the update operation? I'm a little concerned about this: `CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch{`. This is generally a bad pattern and if you do something similar in the update, then without fixing it you can't easily wait for it to finish or cancel.

Comment: It is quite a long one and i have more different ones for each of my fragmens. It includes some more child coroutines, also started with launch or async.

Comment: If you use launch/async by providing a custom scope (and not using the current one), then it is not that easy to wait or cancel the task.

Comment: How should I call cancelAndJoin then? it needs to be in a scope, what scope should I wrap around it?

Comment: I mean potential async/launch inside the update operation. If it launches more coroutines using a custom scope, then these coroutines aren't part of the whole task and they don't care about cancelling or joining. But I mostly speculate here as we don't see what is inside the update operation.

Comment: so if I stay in the same scope and take care that other launch or asyncs are in the same scope, there should be no issues?

Answer (score 0):

What I have managed to do is to check if Job is in transient cancelling state before even calling cancelAndJoin().
Looks like it can arrive in this state: isCompleted:false isCancelled:true isActive:false. Then somehow it still runs even though it gets cancelAndJoin()

In case it is, I just delay till it is not.

```
 while(updateJob.isCancelled && !updateJob.isCompleted && !updateJob.isActive){
                delay(10)
                //old canceled job is still finishing. Wait till it finishes               
            }
updateJob.cancelAndJoin()
updateJob=launch{ ...}
```

Am I doing the right thing? Seems to be fixing the error. I have logged the times that delay gets called and it happens a few times on slower devices, so it fixes the problem.

EDIT:

The answer from @broot is the solution. There should be no
`CoroutineContext(Dispatchers.Default).launch{...}`.
Once in there, the old job still runs in parallel when cancelled till it hits the suspend function. Without it it finishes first before starting again.